# Use single value of parameter List in queryString

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, report, reporting

I am using *JasperStudio 5.6.0.final* and the report is not generated dynamically from java code.

I have a problem with getting single value from parameter.
In the report I have a parameter `A` of a type *List*.

It is not a problem to use it in a clause as `IN` statement:

```
AND $X{IN, USER.ID_USER, A}
```

But I have a problem to get a single value from that list.
I know that my List has always 10 values.
So I want to use it in query, but I don't know how to write the statement:

```
AND USER.ID_USER = *first_value_of_list_A*
```

e.g.

```
AND USER.ID_USER = $P!{Atrybuty}.get(1)
```

doesn't work

I tried also to assign parameter value to a variable, but as I know it isn't possible to use variables in queryString.

So my question: How to get single value from parameter List in queryString.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do for this is use
AND $X{IN, USER.ID_USER, A}
Set A type as Collection and that will allow you to even have a single selection or multi selection or just a single value.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But it's not what I'm searching for. I know that I can put there 1-element list. But I have 10-element list and want to get just first, second, third etc. element independently. I could not send 10 single value parametres cause my api doesn't allow that.